# Why str[0] = 0 clears all string in array?

Tags: c

the given code is:

```c
int main()
{
    char *str = "hello world";
    str[0] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", str); //prints nothing
}
```

I know that I can't edit the part of the string like 'str[5] = 'w;',

so I thought that line 4 'str[i] = 0;' would work like this.

But it seems to clear the string and thus prints nothing.

Can someone please explain why line 4 works like that?

Comment: It sets the string terminator to be at the first element, i.e. the "empty" string. The rest of it is unchanged. (But, that's a string literal and you should not be writing to it.)

Comment: This code exhibits **undefined behavior**, as `str` is pointing at const data. String literals are typically stored in read-only memory.

Comment: The character with value "0" is treated as the termination marker for strings (char arrays), so putting it at position [0] causes the string to have a length of 0.

Comment: First, you need to remove the undefined behavior by changing `char *str =` to `char str[] =`. Then you can show that the array was not cleared by changing the printf to `printf("%s\n", str+1);` which will print `ello world`.

Comment: You can also print the entire array with `for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)  printf("%d\n", str[i]);` You'll see both zeros, the original zero at the end of the array, and the new zero that line 4 put at the beginning of the array. The 32 in the middle is the space character, and the other numbers are the lower case letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0` or `'\0'` is a null character.

In the C language, a string is a null-terminated array of `char`s.

So, if you put `0` at the very first element of the `char` array, it will represent an *empty* string (having length zero) when interpreted as a null-terminated string, such as by the `%s` specifier of `printf()`.

But, your code is invalid, because you can't modify a *string literal*. It has to be more like this instead:

```c
int main()
{
    char str[] = "hello world";
    str[0] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", str); //prints nothing
}
```

Comment: "because you can't modify a string literal" - well, not for quite some time (1989 I believe).  K&R C let you do basically anything :)

Comment: @stdunbar K&R I have no idea. I am not an archaeologist (or even a palaeontologist). but (K&R2, Appendix C) "Strings are no longer modifiable, and so may be placed in read-only memory"